# Left side of screen not working properly

Tags: ios, touch, cgrect

I am trying to make an app where bugs run across the screen and get squashed. I am having a problem though. I have code that makes it so when I touch a bug running across the screen, it disappears. Though, this only works on the right side. This is my code to get rid of the bug.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace: touchLocation];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bug.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {
        [self removeChild:bug cleanup:YES];


    }

}
```

Then, this is my code to spawn the bug on the right side of the screen

```
- (void) addBug {

bug = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bug.jpg"];

CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minY = bug.contentSize.height /2;
int maxY = size.height - bug.contentSize.height /2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

bug.position = ccp(size.width + bug.contentSize.width/2, actualY);
[self addChild:bug];

int minSpeed = 2.0;
int maxSpeed = 4.0;
int rangeSpeed = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeSpeed) + minSpeed;


actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                            position:ccp(-bug.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
    [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}];
[bug runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}

-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
    [self addBug];
}
```

In the init, I have

```
    [self setTouchEnabled:YES];

    [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];
```

I also have a background, if that matters.  I've also tested with logs if the bugs are being touched but not removed on the left side of the screen, when I click the bugs in the simulator, nothing is logged, though when I click them on the right side of the screen, it is logged successfully. Thank you very much for helping.

*Edit, I adjusted the interval for gameLogic:, the left side works when there is only one bug on the screen at once. How should I adjust my code to make this work so there can be multiple bugs on the screen at once and I can still remove them all? I am guessing, the code I am using, creates a bounding box for the most current bug and removes all the other bounding boxes. Any additional help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding bugs on each `gameLogic:` invocation, but you only keep the pointer to the last created which leads to a collision check for a single one in `ccTouchesBegan:withEvent:`. Add each new to an array or whatever data structure that suits your other needs and check against all objects in it.